# Battery state still discharging when AC plugged in. Bad?

Tags: laptop, battery, ubuntu-15.04

Running Ubuntu 15.04 on an ASUS UX305. Runs very well only a minor Fn Key issue to speak of. Though I have noticed that the battery state is always discharging when plugged into AC. I find this strange.

As far as Windows is concerned. It charges to 100% and doesn't seem to be discharging when on AC. I am pretty sure this must be a Linux/Ubuntu issue.

Is this normal behavior? 
Should I worried there is a constant cycling going on?
What other things could I check to rule out this leading to battery life loss?

Edit:
Looking further at this full upower dump things may be a bit odder than first thought. The Display Device seems to be marked as a power supply?

```
upower --dump
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 May 2015 12:42:43 AM EDT (514 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:           'ac-adapter-symbolic`

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 May 2015 12:50:03 AM EDT (74 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              43.023 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         44.414 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45.03 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.14515 W
    voltage:             11.4 V
    time to empty:       13.7 hours
    percentage:          96%
    capacity:            98.632%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 May 2015 12:44:03 AM EDT (434 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              43.023 Wh
    energy-full:         44.414 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.14515 W
    time to empty:       13.7 hours
    percentage:          96%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.2
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: Hybrid/Sleep
```

Comment: You could have a problem with the connector (either on the charger side or laptop side) or with the charger itself. Can you run the laptop on AC with the battery physically removed? If not, try wriggling the connector a little.

Comment: Also, you don't happen to know anyone with the same laptop, do you? If so, you could try swapping out the battery and charger in turn to see which (if either) is at fault.

Comment: Unfortunately the battery is integrated. It doesn't have this problem in Windows.